# How to implement tap-and-hold context menus on WP7

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-7, gestures

The main UI on WP7 uses tap-and-hold everywhere to implement context menus.

I have a `ListBox` that uses `DataTemplate`s for the items. I would like to have a behavior identical to the app list on the main UI. That is, when the user holds down on an item, a context menu appears nearby.

I have read posts here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/e6d2a444-91d9-4d69-937e-689b24c36c09 that enumerate some hacky ways to implement this.

Has Microsoft released any specific guidance on how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5):

The [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) includes a `ContextMenu` for just this situation.

You can find an article on it's use at http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API

Comment: also covered http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/16/pining-for-windows-phone-7-controls-we-got-ya-covered-announcing-the-first-release-of-the-silverlight-for-windows-phone-toolkit.aspx and http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/02/WP7-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-Context-Menus.aspx